# how to create a 2D list with recursion without passing it as an argument to the recursive function, python

Tags: python, list, recursion

i'm trying to figure out a way to make this function to return a 2D list of all subsets in size of k, of group n.
n>=k.

the function accepts 2 numbers, n,k so n>=k. and returns all the possibilities of subset in the size of k of the group {1,2,...,n-1}.

for an example, if the parameters are:
fill_k_subsets(3,2),

the function will output:
[[0,1],[0,2],[1,2]]

which is all possible subsets in the length of 2,
from group{0,1,2}= {0,1,(3-1)}= {1,..,(n-1)} 
hope it's clear enough.

the trick is, to make this work without passing part of the list or any list in general, nor tuple, dictionary, etc. or the subset to any recursive function or the main function
passing list variables or subsets to a non recursive is allowed. 
i would be glad to hear some ideas.
thank you so much.

def fill_k_subsets(n, k):

```
"""
this is the main function, can't accepts more parameters other then k and n. 
accepts n,k natural numbers, and an empty list
all subsets of size k should be stored inside of the empty list
the function does not return  or print anything

:param n:
:param k:
:param list:
:return:
"""

if k <= n:
    set_list= list
    current_subset = [False] * n

    k_fill_helper(current_subset, k, 0, 0, set)
```

def k_fill_helper(current_subset, k, index, choose):

```
 #this is the recursive function.
 #not allowed to accepts any list as a parameter, nor part of the subset
# base case, if chose k items
if k == choose:
    fill_set_list(current_subset, set_list)
    return None
# if we reached to the end of the list
if index == len(current_subset):
    return None
# all subset that that include this index
current_subset[index] = True
k_fill_helper(current_subset, k, index + 1, choose + 1)

# all subset without that index
current_subset[index] = False
k_fill_helper(current_subset, k, index + 1, choose)
```

def fill_set_list(current_subset, set_list):

```
work_list=[]
for index, bool_element in enumerate(current_subset):
    if bool_element is True:
        work_list.append(index)

set_list.append(work_list)
```

Comment: Seems like Python. If so, edit your post and add the Python tag, welcome to SO, good luck with your problem1

Comment: You should correct your code formatting too

Comment: `k_fill_helper()` takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given

Comment: i fixed the argument issue, i managed to make it work only with passing list to the recursive function as an argument. so is there an alternative to make this work without passing a list argument to a recursive function?

Comment: I find it a bit unclear what the function is supposed to do. Can you update your question with a concrete example of input and expected output?